# Mac Pro won't boot from Windows 7 DVD - Flashing prohibitory sign

Tags: windows-7, mac, boot-camp, mac-pro

I am trying to install Windows 7 on my Mac pro, I have tried everything it seems. I have a perfectly good Windows 7 DVD which boots on other devices, yet it doesn't on mine. 
First off it started with spitting out the DVD (which I can understand ;) ), so I thought its my superdrive. 
I went and bought a new drive today, except this is a SATA drive and tried to boot from there. It load the DVD fast and easy within OSX, but when I reboot and try to boot from the disk it hops to a flashing Apple logo and a deny logo (circle with a diagonal line thru it).

What am I doing wrong? The DVD is legal, its not an illegal copy (however, I tried that as well.. and didn't work either). I googled it a bit but cannot find any similar problem.

With flashing logo's, I mean it flashes every second between these two logos:
[image]

***Edit 1*** 
I have now also tried it using Windows 8, downloaded from Microsoft.

***Edit 2*** 
I have now also tried it using an Windows XP Disk. Same problem, flashing icons.

***Edit 3***
I have now also tried:

- Removing all drives and installing OSX 10.6 on one of the 1TB drives.
  Using bootcamp and installing. Same problem
- Reformatted my 750GB Drive and added MBR support. Formatted as Fat drive. Same problem.
- Removing all drives and trying to boot from disk. Nothing happens, just a white screen.
- Reset the PRAM so many times that I guess the computer almost tells me to give it a brake.
- Tried booting with only C hold down. Same problem.

Nothing seems to help.

Also, I just found this page: http://support.Apple.com/KB/HT2674
According to that page, the problem is:

> Circle with Slash - could not load boot.efi, or some other issue

and

> Metallic Apple - found boot.efi.

More: http://support.Apple.com/KB/TS1892?viewlocale=en_US

***Edit 4***
I tried all evening to restore the firmware, but it just refuses. The sleep light flashes a few times, the tone comes, then the normal sound boot sound comes and OSX boot like it should. I am getting crazy here.

***Edit 5***
Tested as well with both 10.5 and 10.6 retail disks, they load perfectly. (Maybe due to that they have GUID formatted?)

Comment: Run the BootCamp Assistant, follow the instructions and insert the DVD when it says to. At what point does it fail?

Comment: If you don't want to use BootCamp see: http://derekhat.com/install-vista-on-a-macbook-without-bootcamp/

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have done. I also tried booting holding ALT and selecting the disk, booting holding C (Come to a screen which informs me no bootable devices are found). I have now also tried it with Windows 8, downloaded directly from Microsoft.

Comment: @Brian I found that site yesterday and tried that as well. Same problem.

Comment: What model is this macbook pro exactly?

Comment: It's a Mac Pro and the model is 3,1. early 2008 model with double quad 2.8 GHz, 4 GB PC6400 ECC, 3.1TB HDD (1TB + 1TB + 350GB + 750GB).

Comment: Is it Windows 7 x64 or 32 ? Are you using a USB mouse and keyboard?

Comment: Its Windows 7 x64. I am using a USB keyboard corrected to the screen which is connected to the Mac Pro. The mouse is bleutooth, but I have also tried it with a plugged in logitech mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple article [EFI and SMC firmware updates for Intel-based Macs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1237)
specifies that MacBook Pro 3.1 can only run EFI 1.5.1.
(From the article you can also download this EFI version.)

As Windows 7 needs EFI version 2, this means that you cannot boot Windows 7 x64 from the DVD.
Some more facts about the EFI problem can be found in [Native UEFI Windows 7 Boot on Mac Mini](http://darobins.wordpress.com/2009/10/04/native-uefi-windows-7-boot-on-mac-mini/).

You will need to convert the Windows 7 DVD that you have to one that can work on the Mac.

Some resources that may help here are :

[Installing Windows 7 x64 on a Mac Pro (Late 2006)](http://timothybrown.tumblr.com/post/110271493/installing-windows-7-x64-on-a-mac-pro-late-2006)
[“Select CD-ROM Boot Type :” prompt during Vista, Server 2008 (& R2) & Windows 7 x64 Boot on Macbook](http://blog.andersonshatch.com/2009/11/08/select-cd-rom-boot-type-prompt-during-vista-server-2008-r2-windows-7-x64-boot-on-macbook/)

Comment: Thanks, it also showed that the EFI is 1.3 for my computer... the Mac Pro (Not MacBook Pro). However, one question: I have a MacBook Pro as well running 1.8 EFI and is boots the Win 7 disk without a problem. Why is that? 
I'm gonna try to install it using your first link tip. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Different models can support different versions, as in the link. But I don't think that for booting Windows 7 there will be a difference between 1.3 and 1.5.

Comment: Ok, I am now downloading the WAIK... I really hope it works. If it does, you're my hero! ;)

Comment: Well, you are my hero. I think some EFI thing was screwed up cause I can now boot from the Windows disk after doing the things from your first list. Thanks!

Comment: Some update would be great, I have expended several hours trying to install Windows 7 on a MacBook (13-inch Late 2006) MacBook2,1 without success, and I remember some warning about updating the firmware.